# with rspec & devise , Why current_user is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
describe 'undertake redirect' do
 let(:user) do
  #このuserはbuildのためデータ保存されていない
  build(:user)
 end
 it 'can get undertake show with authenticate undertake user' do
  user1=build(:user)
  login_user user1
  undertake=create(:undertake)
  visit undertake_path(undertake)
  expect(current_path).to eq undertake_path(undertake)
 end
end
```

This is spec/controllers/undertakes_controller_spec.rb.
and This is undertakescontroller.

```
before_action :user_signed_in?              
def show
  @undertake=Undertake.find_by(id: params[:id])
   @comment=current_user.comments.new
end
```

But current_user is nil. Plobably login_user method is OK. Why current_user is nil?Please help me.

Comment: you'll need to `create` a user (you're just building it) to pass it to `login_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spec you are using the `build` method to reference your user. This does not persist the user in the database and so Devise cannot find a user in the database and thus `current_user` is nil. You should use `create` instead.

Also you should ensure that you have `config.include Warden::Test::Helpers` in your `rails_helper.rb` and use `login_as(user)` to actually log your user in. See [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara) for more info about feature specs with Devise.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I can fix it! but I have a question. I don't understand the difference between login_user and login_as. If you know it , pease tell me . Really ,Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`build(:user)` just "builds" an instance of a user using the `new` method, but it does not actually save that user into the database. Therefore it is not possible to log in as that user.

Use `create(:user)` instead. `create` saves the new instance of user into the database.

Side note: `build` is much faster, because it doesn't use the database, but often you need an actual record from the database with an `id`.